# Starting point for app creating, where to start

Tags: android, ios

I am looking to start writing apps for mobile devices. I know a little about this subjec, and I am proficient in both java and python. However, before jumping into creating apps I wanted to get the community's input on a question I have not yet found the answer to:

- **How/Where should I begin?**

I understand this question is fairly general/basic for a community that focuses on solving/debugging complex programs, but if there is a recommended tutorial (or specific platform) that will help a beginner(such as myself), it would greatly reduce the frustration and amount of monotonous questions asked on this forum and others.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coursera is offering 3 courses all using android development which started last week.  That would be an excellent starting point for anyone:
https://www.coursera.org/specialization/mobilecloudcomputing/2

Answer (score 1):

> - How/Where should I begin?

I don't know about you, but I often learn by example more than reading. You mentioned that you're proficient in java so thats a great start. After you understand the Android SDK it's really only the UI good practices you need to learn. So here's my suggestion.

Start off with something super simple. Let's say, create your own version of a calculator. Something that can add, subtract, multiply, and divide. This should be dirty, ugly, but works correctly.

After doing this, take a look at some other android calculators on the play store. Check out [Simple Loan Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ee.smkv.calc.loan&hl=en). I use this example because it offers a lot of android UI components. [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), etc. Download this app, take a look at it, and try to mimic it. This should provide an idea on how to work with the android UI components.

What's next? After you have done these two apps you should be relatively ready to tackle your own project.

Answer (score 0):

HTML apps are easy to port across multiple mobile platforms.  I have set up an Android HTML template as a starting point.  You can just import this project into Eclipse and take a look at that.

https://github.com/jakewp11/HTML5_Android_Template

Answer (score 0):

Here is my experience for ios, 
There are three things that I consider as pillars

1. Objective C
2. Memory managment
3. Design patterns

The first one looks obvious but I'd stress on learning concepts like protocols, categories, extensions. As a beginner I thought that learning the syntax  was enough, but time and again I had to jump back to the language concepts to understand what's going.

The memory managment , the most talked and confusing subject and now since we have automatic referenc counting to make things simpler and often new Dev skips learning memory concepts (I did it). So I suggest you to have an idea what actually happens under the hood of arc " the manual memory managment"

The design patters, 
When I started off , to pass data and control , what I used to do was achieve every thing through the only design patten I knew (target action) . I lack the knowledge of design patters didn't how easily I could achive better results with less code.

Some resources:
Dev.apple.com
http://www.raywenderlich.com (one of my best tutorials are here, you can find one on design patterns)
http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/

And yes , the sample projects at Dev.apple are the best tutors.